# Scatter plot with pareto frontier using gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot, scatter-plot

I can currently use gnuplot to plot a scatter graph. But what I am unable to do is connect all the points on the graph which form the rightmost frontier(i.e these points do not have any points further to their right)

Here's an example of a scatter plot with rightmost frontier.
http://www.schoolbenchmarking.com/Images/FrontierPlot.gif

Any clues on how to achieve this would help a lot!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK gnuplot does not have a feature determining the outer border of a plot.

Since you can include scripts in gnuplot, you could program your own logic into it. But I think it would be easier if you just create another data set and plot that as a solid line.